# redirect non-www to www for an internal page's url

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to redirect:

- domain.co.uk to www.domain.co.uk and
- domain.co.uk/contact-us to www.domain.co.uk/contact-us.

I have tried dozen of `web.config` rules with ECMAScript and Wildcard  but first one is done but second one either remain same or redirect to www.domain.co.uk i.e. home page. A example of what is there at the moment is as below:

```
  <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.co.uk/*" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.co.uk/{C:1}/{R:0}"  />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect to the www version while preserving the HTTP and HTTPS protocol:

```
<rule name="ensurewww" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://(?!www)(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://www.{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```